# Next Auth useSession does not get session at first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to build a website using NextJS v13 and Next Auth v4. Whenever a page/component is loaded, the session is not returned in the first render when using `useSession` hook and because of this, many components don't work like they should...

For instance, the following code should load the questions for authenticated users:

```js
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Question } from '@prisma/client'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

function QuestionPage() {
  const { data: session } = useSession() // this is null
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<Question[]>([])
  const [questionStatus, setQuestionStatus] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Session: ', session)
    if (!session) return;

    setQuestionStatus('Loading questions...');

    fetch('/api/questions')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setQuestions(data.questions)
            setQuestionStatus('');
        })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{questionStatus}</p>
      {questions && questions.map(question => {
         <p key={question.id}>{question.title}</p>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is my `ProviderWrapper` component that wraps the main app:

```js
'use client'
import QuestionContextWrapper from '@/context/QuestionContext'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My App',
  description: 'My description',
}

export default function ProvidersWrapper({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <QuestionContextWrapper>
        {children}
      </QuestionContextWrapper>
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

And this is the `layout.tsx` file:

```js
import './globals.css'
import Header from '@/components/Header'
import ProvidersWrapper from './ProvidersWrapper'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My app',
  description: 'My description',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ProvidersWrapper>
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </ProvidersWrapper>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Anyone knows why is `next-auth` behaving like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial load session will be undefined since it's not pass to provider. Try to pass ***existing session*** to provider like below.

```
export default function ProvidersWrapper({ children, session }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider baseUrl={/* BASE_URL */} refetchInterval={60 * 5} session={session}>
      <QuestionContextWrapper>{children}</QuestionContextWrapper>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

ProvidersWrapper.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const { ctx } = context;
  const session = await getSession(ctx);

  return {
    session,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research and due to the @Thusithz's answer, I have found [this guide](https://blog.bitsrc.io/adding-nextauth-to-nextjs-13-and-authenticating-with-github-40539ca6a81c) to implement proper authentication using Next Auth and TypeScript. So I changed my code to the following and it worked.

I have renamed `/src/components/PriverWrapper.tsx` to `src/context/AuthProvider.tsx` and changed the code as well to the following:

```js
'use client'
import { Session } from 'next-auth'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My App',
  description: 'My description',
}

export interface AuthContextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
  session: Session
}

export default function AuthContext({ children }: AuthContextProps) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
}
```

And then applied this to the `/src/app/layout.tsx` file wrapping the node with `AuthProvider` and passing the `session` variable:

```js
import './globals.css'
import Header from '@/components/Header'
import AuthProvider from '@/context/AuthContext'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'
import { Session } from 'next-auth'

async function getSession(cookie: string): Promise<Session> {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/session`, {
    headers: {
      cookie,
    }
  })

  const session = await response.json()

  return Object.keys(session).length > 0 ? session : null
}

export const metadata = {
  title: 'My app',
  description: 'My description',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const session = await getSession(headers().get('cookie') ?? '');
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AuthContext session={session}>
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </AuthContext >
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

So, this works as expeted.